# How to compare the column values of the max and min dates of a group of rows in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case

Given a table that looks like this, how would I go about creating another query that takes this data, compares sales_net_amt from the earliest and latest date for that store_id, and returns one row per store_id displaying plain text for whether it "increased" or "decreased" overtime in another column?

[image]

For the calculated column, I'm assuming I could just use a "case when" clause, but I'm not sure how I could derive the two separate values of the latest and earliest dates to do the comparison.
The best I could do was create a query that displayed the latest and earliest dates and their sales_net_amt, but I have no idea how I can add the calculated column to base off of the existing values

[image]

This is the query I made (the QUARTER column is unneeded and makes the query unnecessarily verbose, just figured I would add it for the time being in case I do end up using it):

```
select case when extract(month from full_date) between 1 and 3 then substr(item_scan_timestamp, -4) || 'Q1'
     when extract(month from full_date) between 4 and 6 then substr(item_scan_timestamp, -4) || 'Q2'
     when extract(month from full_date) between 7 and 9 then substr(item_scan_timestamp, -4) || 'Q3'
     when extract(month from full_date) between 10 and 12 then substr(item_scan_timestamp, -4) || 'Q4' end quarter, r.store_id, p.full_date, r.sales_net_amt
from retailsalesfact r join purchasedate p on p.purchase_date_id = r.purchase_date_id
where (r.store_id, p.full_date) in (select r.store_id, max(p.full_date) full_date
        from retailsalesfact r join purchasedate p on p.purchase_date_id = r.purchase_date_id
        group by r.store_id)
union all
select case when extract(month from full_date) between 1 and 3 then substr(item_scan_timestamp, -4) || 'Q1'
     when extract(month from full_date) between 4 and 6 then substr(item_scan_timestamp, -4) || 'Q2'
     when extract(month from full_date) between 7 and 9 then substr(item_scan_timestamp, -4) || 'Q3'
     when extract(month from full_date) between 10 and 12 then substr(item_scan_timestamp, -4) || 'Q4' end quarter, r.store_id, p.full_date, r.sales_net_amt
from retailsalesfact r join purchasedate p on p.purchase_date_id = r.purchase_date_id
where (r.store_id, p.full_date) in (select r.store_id, min(p.full_date) full_date
        from retailsalesfact r join purchasedate p on p.purchase_date_id = r.purchase_date_id
        group by r.store_id)
order by store_id, full_date, sales_net_amt;

select store_id, full_date, sales_net_amt
from retailsalesfact r join purchasedate p on p.purchase_date_id = r.purchase_date_id
order by store_id;
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What version of Oracle DB are you running?

Comment: @etch_45 Oracle 12c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `FULL_DATE` column is actually a date, you could use [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm#SQLRF00642) and [`LAST_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions078.htm#SQLRF00655) to get the first and last values by date and then compare them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STORE_ID,
       CASE WHEN LAST_VALUE(SALES_NET_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY STORE_ID ORDER BY FULL_DATE) >
                 FIRST_VALUE(SALES_NET_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY STORE_ID ORDER BY FULL_DATE) THEN 'Increased'
            ELSE 'Decreased'
       END AS SALES_CHANGE
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you explain the key differences between this method and @Tejash's method? I never knew about window and analytical functions until after reading your answer and doing some research on it, so I'm confused as to exactly what each part of the query is doing.

Comment: @Andrew this query uses window functions (`last_value` and `first_value`) which effectively sort the rows by `full_date` and choose the value of `sales_net_amt` corresponding to those rows, where the other solution does aggregation using `keep` to filter the rows on which it does the aggregation. I suspect this query will be faster - it's a little less complicated - but it'd be interesting to see performance results on real data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `KEEP` clause in `GROUP BY` as you want one record per store as follows:

```
select store_id, 
       case when max(SALES_NET_AMT) keep (dense_rank first order by FULL_DATE desc) 
                  > max(SALES_NET_AMT) keep (dense_rank first order by FULL_DATE) 
            then 'Increased' 
            else 'Decreased' 
      end as result
  from your_Table t
group by store_id
```

Comment: Hey this works great! Can you explain what the keep clause does in this scenario? Could you have also partitioned the data as part of the window function as opposed to using the group by clause?

Comment: KEEP clause gives the data based on other values of the group.  You must read about it from oracle documentation.